# How to create android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

As I am new to android so I am confused in layout managers, which should I use for my project?
Please help in understanding the layout managers. As my I want to create layout contains views in the form of table layout having two rows and two columns.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this great resouce](http://www.google.com/?q=android%20table%20layout%20managers). Tons of information out there,

If you don't like reading, there's even a youtube video that does exactly what you ask.

If you just want a copy-paste solution, try this. With some minor tweaking it should give you what you want :

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Name:" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et_name"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="URL:" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et_url"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: this is not even close to an answer

Comment: it was not a real question either.... It's clear that no effort was done to even remotely investigate this. A basic Google search will provide him with a lot more information. The second search result is a youtube video that explains in details what he needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) to get an overview of the various Layout types and how to use them.